# How to pass class instance as a handle in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

A hypothetical scenario to ask my question:

Let's say we have 2 entities: a boss and an employee. When an employee completes a job, he/she wants to let people know. In this case, the boss 'kind of' subscribes to the message and decides what to do

I implemented this interface which has an abstract method that any other class can implemented. In this  (cause he/she will decide what he/she wants to do):

```
classdef (Abstract) Interface < handle

    methods
        getJobsCompleted(n)
    end

end
```

The boss class inherits Interface and implements the method getJobsCompleted()

```
classdef Boss < Interface & handle

    properties
        myEmployee
    end

    methods
        function this = Boss()
            this.myEmployee = Employee(this)

            this.myEmployee.doJobs();
        end
        %My boss implements (i.e. decides what to do) the abstract method
        function getJobsCompleted(n)

            %DO SOMETHING with n
        end
    end

end
```

And, finally, the employee performs the jobs and notifies the boss.

```
classdef Employee < handle

    properties
        numJobsCompleted;
        boss = [];%pointer or reference to Boss instance
    end

    methods
        function this = Employee(myBoss)
            this.boss = myBoss; %reference/pointer to my boss so I know who to notify
        end

        function doJobs()
           %% do something then let boss know
           this.numJobsCompleted = 40;
           this.boss.getJobsCompleted(this.numJobsCompleted);
        end

    end

end
```

What I have been attempting to unsuccessfully do is to pass a reference to the Employee class so that he/she knows which boss to notify.

i.e.

```
in Boss
this.myEmployee = Employee(this)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, you just need to explicitly accept the object instance as an input argument to all methods. You'll need to update the following two function definitions:

```
function doJobs(this)
function getJobsCompleted(this, n)
```

That being said, a better way of doing this may be to use [events and listeners](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners--concepts.html). You would then have the employee emit a "JobCompleted" event and have the boss listen to those events for all of their employees. This prevents the employee from needing to keep track of their boss.

```
classdef Boss < handle

    properties
        Employees
        Listeners
    end

    methods
        function this = Boss(employees)
            this.Employees = employees;

            this.Listeners = addlistener(employees, 'JobCompleted', @this.onJobCompleted);
        end

        function onJobCompleted(this, employee, evnt)
            fprintf('%s completed a job!\n', employee.Name);
        end
    end
end
```

**`Employee.m`**

```
classdef Employee < handle

    properties
        Name
        CompletedJobs = 0
    end

    events
        JobCompleted
    end

    methods
        function this = Employee(name)
            this.Name = name;
        end

        function doJob(this)
            this.CompletedJobs = this.CompletedJobs + 1;
            notify(this, 'JobCompleted')
        end
    end
end
```

And use it like:

```
employees(1) = Employee('Fred');
employees(2) = Employee('Bill');

boss = Boss(employees);

doJob(employees);
doJob(employees(1));
```